# Google Chrome and kerberos authentication against Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, kerberos, google-chrome

I've managed to get kerberos authentication to work now with Apache and Likewise Open but so far, Google Chrome doesn't seem to play fair.

Unless I start it with `chrome.exe --auth-server-whitelist="*company.com"` it does only pop-up a login window but will not accept any credentials at all.

As far as I know, the `--auth-server-whitelist` option should only be used when trying to get Single-Sign-On (SSO) to work, but if you are fine with a log-in window it should work directly out of the box, but so far it doesn't.

This is the error I get in the apache logs.

> [Tue Dec 13 08:49:04 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.15] failed to
>   verify krb5 credentials: Unknown code krb5 7

Comment: What version of windows / chrome do you use to test it?  Does SSO on IE / firefox works OK ? What if you typed in the username and password twice ? I have a problem where apache ask for credentials twice : http://serverfault.com/questions/100288/apache-mod-auth-kerb-asking-2-authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the server is in Local Intranet zone: this matters for SSPI wich Chrome seems to use.

Comment: That was all it took in my case. Nice one!